# React Native: How to render a number of conditional views with coupled conditions?

Tags: react-native, reactjs

One of my components has about four different states it could be in, each with their own full-screen views (loading, error/retry, and 2 others).

Right now my render function looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            {this.renderLoadingView()}
            {this.renderEmptyView()}
            {this.renderErrorView()}
            {this.renderInterviewListView()}
            {this.renderInterviewFeedbackRequestViews()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

But each of the others look something like this where they either render null if they don't meet a number of conditions or they render the view if all are met:

```
renderLoadingView() {
    if (this.state.showLoading && !this.state.showError) {
        return (
            <View>
                [...]
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

renderErrorView() {
    if (this.state.showError) {
        return (
            <InterviewsErrorView onRetry={() => this.onRefresh()}/>
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

renderInterviewListView() {
    var showEmpty = this.state.emptyFeedbackRequests && this.state.emptyInterviews;
    if (this.state.showLoading || this.state.showError || showEmpty) {
        return null;
    } else if (!this.state.emptyFeedbackRequests) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (
            <View>
                [...]
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

This feels messy, especially since multiple views depend on the same thing (e.g. whether or not showLoading is true). Is there a way I can simplify this or make it cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your conditions in render method and remove it from your helper methods. Your render method should look like :

```
render() {

  const showEmpty = this.state.emptyFeedbackRequests && this.state.emptyInterviews;

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        { this.state.showLoading && this.state.showError && this.renderLoadingView()}
        {this.renderEmptyView()}
        {this.state.showError && this.renderErrorView()}
        {(this.state.showLoading || this.state.showError || shosEmpty) && this.renderInterviewListView()}
        {this.renderInterviewFeedbackRequestViews()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

This would make your helper methods cleaner and will remove else part as well from them. By looking at your question I couldn't determine the common code among your Views.

But if there is something common, you can further optimise code and decrease number of helper methods by introducing parameters in method.